# To Keep my progress bar running while clicking submit button and to freeze the screen and the background code should run

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I need the progress bar running while submit button is clicked and to freeze the screen for some 5 seconds but the code in the submit button should do the work in parallel.

I have created a wait form but I have called the wait form once the connection is closed so that progress bar is taking time to appear and I can select the other options in the screen which is shouldn't.

```cs
private void cmdselect_click(System.object _sender System.EventArgs e1)
{
    using (frmwait frm=new frmwait(savedata)) //  and I have called wait form here
    {
        frm.Showdialog(this)
    }
}

// Savedata method

void Savedata()
{
    for(int i=1;i<=500;i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

Progress bar is not starting immediately once the button click is fired.

Comment: I am currently using a pop up progress bar that I created after watching this video: - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZYAaScEsc0. I just realised I shared my code for it in this stackoverflow answer: - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57377016/how-to-load-the-progressbar-at-the-same-time-my-method-is-running

Comment: I have done the same by watching this.

Comment: I went back and looked at my code and I call the progress bar form exactly the same as you do. Mine appears instantly so I think the problem must be in the code for your progress bar form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
progressBar.Minimum = 0;
progressBar.Maximum = 500;
progressBar.Value = 0;
progressBar.Step = 1;
progressBar.Refresh();

Enabled = false;               // for UX
Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;   // for UX
try
{
  for( int i = 1; i <= progressBar.Maximum; i++ )
  {
    // do process
    progressBar.PerformStep();
    progressBar.Refresh();
    Thread.Sleep(10);
  }
}
finally
{
  Cursor = Cursors.Default;
  Enabled = true;
}
```

No need to Sleep unless you want to reduce the speed of the process.

Comment: while hitting progressbar.Value=0 its throws an system.argumentnullexception saying value cannot be null.

Comment: How do you create the bar? By the designer while drop it on the form or by code and is it created before usage?

Comment: by designer i have in another form i am trying to access it.

Comment: Have you changed the other form constructor? It must have InitializeComponents call at first.

Comment: Yes right what i have to change there I have intializecomponent() if (worker==null) {throw argument null exception}

Comment: You should avoid throwing exception in constructor or you must manage the case in a try catch either in the constructor either when calling new Form.

Comment: I have change the style .I have kept Marquee it is saying perform step cannot be performed in that style.

Comment: Yes, steps can't be used with marquee that is only an animation without min and max ans setp: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312936/windows-forms-progressbar-easiest-way-to-start-stop-marquee

Comment: the code is working fine but progress bar is not displaying.

Comment: Can you make a link to a zip of the project folder?

Comment: I work in VMware we cant copy the code or zip thats the issue.

Comment: Do you show the form? Where is the bar in the form? Is the Visible property on?

Comment: I have progress bar in another form i Called from there frmwait.progressbar1.show(); but it is not displaying and also i have visible to true.

Comment: Have you called frmwait.Show() ?

Comment: Yeah i have called now but the background doesnt freeze also progress bar keeps progressing it doesnt hide.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.Lastly if i use form.show() its working fine but form.showdialog its getting struck but I have freeze parent form

Comment: Yes, ShowDialog() wait to Close() before returning to the caller. So to show a splash you need to use Show() and you can also disable the caller form by using this.Enabled = false for example like in the answer updated.

Comment: Its working perfectly but one issue is that whenever i click on parent form the processing form(child form) gets minimized anyway to overcome this ?

Comment: You can set the splash form `TopMost` property to `true`. Hence if the user click on the background caller form the splash will remain on top.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help it all went fine :)